# How to quickly compare many strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have a string column that contains numbers.  Each entry I need is only one number so no parsing is needed.  I need some way to find all rows that contain numbers from 400 to 450.  Instead of doing:

```
...where my stringcolumn like '%400%' or stringcolumn like '%401%' or stringcolumn like '%402%' or ...
```

is there a better that can save on some typing?

There are also other values in these rows such as: '5335154', test4559@me.com', '555-555-5555'. Filtering those out will need to be taken into account.

Comment: What do the strings look like?  Do you want to match 1401 as well as 401?  Do you want to match 14010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...where stringcolumn like '4[0-4][0-9]' OR stringcolumn = '450'
```

You don't need the wildcard if you want to restrict to 3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to accomplish this.

```
...where stringcolumn like '4[0-4][0-9]' OR stringcolumn like '450'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to restrict it to purely 3 digits?  It's picking up other stuff such as '5335154', test4559@me.com', '555-555-5555'.  Should have been more clear about that in the question.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
WHERE Column like '%4[0-4][09]%'
OR Column LIKE '%500%'
```

keep in mind that this will pick anything with the number in it, so 5000 will be returned as well

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (case when charindex('4', col) > 0
                   then substrint(col, charindex('4', col), charindex('4', col) + 2)
              end) as col4xx
      from t
     ) t
where (case when isnumeric(col4xx) = 1
            then (case when cast(col4xx as int) between 400 and 450 then 'true'
                  end)
       end) = 'true'
```

I'm not a fan of having case statements in WHERE clauses.  However, to ensure conversion to a number, this is needed (or the conversion could become a column in another subquery).  Note that the following is not equivalent:

```
where col4xx between '400' and '450'
```

Since the string '44A' would match.